# Route crashes heroku-app but works on localhost

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, mongoose

I have a working backend which is running on Heroku. The client is a react-app.
Everything works fine until a specific router request is made.

I've read many posts about apps working locally but not on Heroku. The difference is that I can get my app to start and function normally until a specific post-request is made to the server.

This is the route. The console.logs are for debugging. I first want to check that a user hasn't voted on that specific answer before, then the user can vote.

```js
router.post('/:qID/answers/:aID/vote-:dir',function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body, "THIS IS THE REQ.BODY");
    console.log(req.params.aID);
        if(req.params.dir.search(/^(up|down)$/) === -1) {
            var err = new Error("Not found");
            err.status = 404;
            next(err);
        } else {
            req.vote = req.params.dir;
            req.userId = req.body.userId;
            next();
        }
    },
    function(req, res, next){
        console.log(req.body, "IS THIS THE SAME VALUE?");
        try{
        User.findById(req.userId, (err, user) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err, "IS THIS AN ERROR?");
                next(err);
            }
            if(user.answersVoted.length > 0) {
                for(let i = 0; i < user.answersVoted.length; i++){
                    if (user.answersVoted[i] == req.answer._id){
                        req.answered = true;
                    } else {
                        req.answered = false;
                    }
                } return next();
            } else {
                updateAnswerArrayandVote(req, res);
            }
        });
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err, "IS THIS AN ERROR TOO?");
        return next(err);
    }
        
}, function(req, res, next){
    if(req.answered){
        res.status(422).json({message: "Only vote once!"});
    } else {
        updateAnswerArrayandVote(req, res);
    }
});
```

This is the client side

```js
handleVote = (id, dir) => {
        if (dir === "up") {
            axios.post(`https://sleepy-falls-59530.herokuapp.com/questions/${this.state.id}/answers/${id}/vote-up`, {
              userId: this.props.userId
            })
            .then(res => {console.log(res)})
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              this.setState({
                show: true
              })
            })
        } else {
            axios.post(`https://sleepy-falls-59530.herokuapp.com/questions/${this.state.id}/answers/${id}/vote-down`, {
              userId: this.props.userId
            }).then(res => {console.log(res)})
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              this.setState({
                show: true
              })
            })
        }
    }
```

This is the error message from the heroku logs:

```
]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2019-07-09T16:04:09.523006+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-07-09T16:04:09.523009+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-07-09T16:04:09.523012+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
2019-07-09T16:04:09.523015+00:00 app[web.1]: at User.findById (/app/routes.js:329:34)
2019-07-09T16:04:09.523017+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4645:16
2019-07-09T16:04:09.523019+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4004:12
2019-07-09T16:04:09.523023+00:00 app[web.1]: at process.nextTick (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2622:28)
2019-07-09T16:04:09.523025+00:00 app[web.1]: at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
2019-07-09T16:04:09.523027+00:00 app[web.1]: at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
2019-07-09T16:04:09.569320+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-07-09T16:04:09.570120+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-07-09T16:04:09.573462+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! restAPI@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2019-07-09T16:04:09.573822+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-07-09T16:04:09.574525+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
```

It seems like the User.findById() isn't working in heroku, since the answersVoted-array on the user object is undefined. How come this is working locally and more importantly, how can I fix it? I know I am sending a correct value since the console.logs are shown in the logs (not included in this post though). Thanks in advance!

EDIT

So the heroku logs gives me this:

```
MuPuLM8q9i6A1a3uFvUzD8K2EbsGkaRt.QlHmBlMi3ry5ZK',
2019-07-10T18:52:49.981062+00:00 app[web.1]: __v: 1,
2019-07-10T18:52:49.981064+00:00 app[web.1]: answersVoted:
2019-07-10T18:52:49.981066+00:00 app[web.1]: [ '5d0bed720498750dbcc31b3e',
2019-07-10T18:52:49.981067+00:00 app[web.1]: '5ceac5948761ba2b4c2f7a7e',
2019-07-10T18:52:49.981069+00:00 app[web.1]: '5d0bed720498750dbcc31b3e',
2019-07-10T18:52:49.981072+00:00 app[web.1]: '5d17524e4dfec60016a07609',
2019-07-10T18:52:49.981074+00:00 app[web.1]: '5d0bed720498750dbcc31b3e',
2019-07-10T18:52:49.981076+00:00 app[web.1]: '5d17524e4dfec60016a07609',
2019-07-10T18:52:49.981078+00:00 app[web.1]: '5cf90359990b3233a0fbb1ce',
2019-07-10T18:52:49.981080+00:00 app[web.1]: '5d17524e4dfec60016a07609' ] } 'THE USER'
2019-07-10T18:52:49.981088+00:00 app[web.1]: THE USER IS A object
2019-07-10T18:52:49.981159+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined 'THE USERS ANSWERSARRAY'
2019-07-10T18:52:49.983370+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

And the code for that is:

```js
 User.findById(req.userId, async (err, user) => {
            console.log(user, "THE USER");
            console.log("THE USER IS A", typeof user);
            console.log(user.answersVoted, "THE USERS ANSWERSARRAY");
```

As you can see I am able to access the user object with the answersVoted-array shown.

`console.log(user)`Shows me the user and all the nested objects, including the answersVoted-array

`console.log(user.answersVoted)` undefined.

Asynchronous error or something with heroku (since it works with postman)? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to reset your DB locally ? Maybe your local data are well formatted to not see that error.

Comment: I am still using the same database even if i'm trying it out locally.
If i try the route on my localhost from postman it works but if i try the route on heroku from postman i get a html response saying "Application Error" and the above error message from the heroku logs. Is it maybe a cors-problem?

Comment: So you mean your database is running on your laptop or is it already hosted somewhere ?

Comment: The database is hosted on mlab

Comment: The only way the route works correct if i use postman as "front end" and then requesting the express-app running on localhost.

Comment: @GaëlS please see my edit in the post above.

Comment: Strange indeed. Do you perform the exact same request with postman and the frontend (id, query params, everything ) ?

Comment: So I must be the stupidest boy in school. After comparing the code it turns out I forgot to add the answersVoted array to the User model in my User-schema. I am so sorry for taking your time with my stupidity but still grateful for you trying to help me. The router now works. Thank you @GaëlS !

Comment: No worries, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Always remember to actually add the property to your Mongoose Model's Schema if you later want to use it, say in a express router...